# Change permission request alert in Webview within react native app for IOS (EXPO)

Tags: ios, react-native, webview, expo, dropzone

I am building a small ios app which runs within the react-native-webview. The webpage as a dropzone input where you can upload fotos through the webbrowser. In the react native app, there is also the option to capture a foto directly form the device camera. Now, the apple reaview team told me to:

> We continue to notice that your app requests the user’s consent to access the camera, but doesn’t sufficiently explain the use of the camera in the purpose string.

> To help users make informed decisions about how their data is used, all permission request alerts need to specify how your app will use the requested information.

> Next Steps

> Please revise the relevant purpose string in your app’s Info.plist file to specify why your app needs access to the user's camera. Make sure the purpose string includes an example of how the user's data will be used.

> You can modify your app's Info.plist file using the property list editor in Xcode.

But I can't because, the request is from the webview and not from the react native app itself! I tried to do in the app.json like this:

```
"infoPlist": {
    "NSCameraUsageDescription": "Damit du direkt ein Bild von deinem Artikel machen kannst, erlaube den Zugirff auf deine Kamera.",
    "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "Wähle ein Bild aus deinen Photos aus für dein Inserat."
  }
```

But there is no change. How can I modify the alerts or is there an option to disable direct capture from the camera in the webview or in the dropzone plugin?

Comment: did you find any solution for this, i am stuck in this as well.

Comment: I'm facing the same issues, any news ?